# regex to capture part of the string that contains tabs/spaces and substring from text file

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a text file that has the following info:

```
"Where_can_i_find        red    capture    state"
"Why_are_you        orange    00:AO    state"
"Salty_pepper        gray    good    state"

with open(cur_path,'r') as file:
    data = file.read()
    itm1 = re.search('Where_can_i_find        (.+?)state',data.group(1)
    itm2 = re.search('Salty_pepper        (.+?)state',data.group(1)
```

This will give me `red    capture` and `gray    good` etc...But I only want to get `capture` for the first item and `good` for the second item without the `red` and `gray` part.  In other words I want to skip everything on the 2nd column.

How should I change my regex for this to work?

Comment: Maybe you want `for line in file:` , `if line.strip().endswith('state') and any(line.strip().startswith(x) for x in ['Where_can_i_find','Salty_pepper']):` -> `print(line.split()[-2])`? See https://ideone.com/mo6BVT

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The file has many many lines and I don't want to split them all only specific ones that I need.  I want first search for the line that I need (for example: Where_can_i_find )

Comment: That is exactly what I suggest, see `endswith` and `startswith` conditions. The Caspar's answer is following the same logic with a costly regex operation (see a lazy dot and `\S+` pattern following it causing a lot of backtracking). If you do not need a regex, like here, why use a regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
for line in file:
    if line.strip().endswith('state') and any(line.strip().startswith(x) for x in ['Where_can_i_find','Salty_pepper']):
        print(line.split()[-2])
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/mo6BVT).

*Notes*:

- `line.strip().endswith('state')` - checks if the line ends with `state`
- `any(line.strip().startswith(x) for x in ['Where_can_i_find','Salty_pepper'])` - checks if the line starts with one of the specified strings.

Answer (score 1):

The `\s` (any whitespace) and `\S` (non-whitespace) classes are useful here.

To match a single non-whitespace sequence `\S+`, separated with a single whitespace sequence `\s+` right before `state`:

```
re.search(r'Where_can_i_find.*?(\S+)\s+state',data).group(1)

re.search(r'Salty_pepper.*?(\S+)\s+state',data).group(1)
```

Since you mention 'columns', another approach would be to split the whole thing into columns first, and then select the right items. For instance:

```
data = '''Where_can_i_find        red    capture    state
Why_are_you        orange    00:AO    state
Salty_pepper        gray    good    state'''

data_split = [line.split() for line in data.splitlines()]

data_dict = {line[0]: line[2] for line in data_split}

> data_dict
{'Where_can_i_find': 'capture',
 'Why_are_you': '00:AO',
 'Salty_pepper': 'good'}
```

Since this avoids regexes, it can be a lot faster (perhaps depending on how many of the lines you actually want to access).

Comment: `"Salty pepperoni state"` captures `"oni"`. Consider `^(?:Where_can_i_find|Salty_pepper) +\S+ +([a-z]+) +state$`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland The underscore does not match a space, but indeed the regex could be more strict. Don't forget to add the re.MULTILINE flag if you use ^ and $ to match the start and end of a line, instead of those of a file.

`re.search('^Salty_pepper\s+\S+\s+(\S+)\s+state$',data, re.MULTILINE).group(1)`

Comment: Right, `"Salty pepperoni state"` should have been `"Salty_pepperoni state"`.

Answer (score 0):

If all your lines end with state, then you can use:`(\S+)(?=\s+state)`
Test here: https://regex101.com/r/HQVXRe/1

Since you want to get the second column of specific lines, you can use `startswith` to find such lines and the use `re.search`.

```py
import re

s = '''"Where_can_i_find        red    capture    state"
"Why_are_you        orange    00:AO    state"
"Salty_pepper        gray    good    state"'''
lines  = s.split('\n')

pattern = re.compile(r'(\S+)(?=\s+state)', re.M)
prefixes = ('"Where_can_i_find','"Salty_pepper')

for line in lines:
    if(line.startswith(prefixes)):
        print(pattern.findall(line))
# capture
# good
```